# I use session to keep track user on site - is there better way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-state

I have a little architecture issue.
On my site user can register and when they log in on site based on userID I redirect user to his profile page (something like facebook).
User can from this page click on another user from list and go to his profile page.
When user come on his friend profile page he can access to some links on that page to see more information on this friend (like his friends list, images, info etc.).
So what I am doing now is when user click on his friend I save friendID in Session. 
And later when I need access something I first get data from session and go.
I wonder is this approach good or bad?
It works but I wonder is there better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it's not a good design. This is like using a global variable to reference the "current friend". Obviously, this makes it impossible to view information about two different friends at once, by opening the "friend info" page in another browser tab or window, for example.

It also couples the "friend info" page to the "friend list" page. This means that any other page which wants to link to the friend info page must put the friend ID in the session, and that you're forced to go through one of these pages to see a friend info. If the user bookmarks the friend info page, closes his session, reopens one, and uses his bookmark, it will fail.

And finally, it makes the application stateful, whereas it could stay stateless by having the "friend list" page simply link to the "friend info" page by using a link such as `friendInfo?friendId=<the friend ID>`.

Comment: And where for example facebook keep track data. When I visi some frien page on fb (fb.com/someFriend) and when I remove 'someFriend' from URL and click info I get that friend info. From where ID data ha been read?

Comment: I'm one of these 4 developers in the world who don't have a Facebook account. Sorry. If the URL for the friend *JohnSmith* is `fb.com/JohnSmith`, then you have your answer: it extracts the ID of the friend (JohnSmith) from the URL.

Comment: I have it just to clone some features :) That's what confuse me if I remove JohnSmith from url it still knows on which user info I clicked.

Comment: Keeping track of the last visited friend could be a good idea, but relying on this single last visited friend to display all the information related to a friend is not a good idea, IMO.